# Evenly distributed integers within a range

Tags: php, integer, numbers, range

Lets say I have a range between 0 and 100 and I want an array returned containing 3 integers which are evenly distributed within that range, what would be the best way to do this?

For example:

Range: 0-100
Wanted: 3
Returned: 25, 50, 75

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting what a uniform distribution means?

Comment: so you want to partition the range into N+1 sections?  (0-25, 26-50, 51-75, 76-100) and know what the partition value is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
function distributeIntegers(int wanted, int rangeLow, int rangeHigh)
    int increment = (rangeHigh - rangeLow) / (wanted + 1)
    array r = new array()
    for (int i = rangeLow + increment; i < rangeHigh; i += increment)
        r.push(i)
    return r
```

PHP:

```
function distributeIntegers($wanted = 3, $rangeLow = 0, $rangeHigh = 100){
    $increment = ($rangeHigh - $rangeLow) / ($wanted + 1);
    $r = array();
    for ($i = $rangeLow + $increment; $i < $rangeHigh; $i += $increment)
        $r []= $i;
    return $r;
}
/*
  examples:

  call:
      distributeIntegers();
  returns:
             [0] => 25
             [1] => 50
             [2] => 75

  call:
      distributeIntegers(4);
  returns:
             [0] => 20
             [1] => 40
             [2] => 60
             [3] => 80

  call:
      distributeIntegers(5, 50, 200);
  returns:
             [0] => 75
             [1] => 100
             [2] => 125
             [3] => 150
             [4] => 175
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make use of array_chunk(), eg only

```
$end=100;
$a = range(0,$end);
$chunk=3;
foreach (array_chunk($a,$end/($chunk+1)) as $s){
     print $s[0]."\n";
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
0
25
50
75
100
```

you can get rid of the start (0) and end(100) points if not needed.

Comment: horribly inefficient if a `$end` is a large number though, since you're creating an array with `$end` elements

Comment: yes, i assumed OP has an array with a range of numbers already.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in groovy that gives the answers you want, you should be able to switch it to whatever language you're using:

```
def distributedValues(min, max, wanted) {
   def incrementBy = (max - min)/(wanted + 1)
   (1..wanted).collect { count -> min + (count * incrementBy) }
}


assert distributedValues(0, 100, 1) == [50]
assert distributedValues(0, 100, 3) == [25, 50, 75]
assert distributedValues(0, 100, 4) == [20, 40, 60, 80]
assert distributedValues(0, 100, 5) == [16.6666666667, 33.3333333334, 50.0000000001, 66.6666666668, 83.3333333335]
assert distributedValues(100, 200, 3) == [125, 150, 175]
```

Comment: :O it looks like python, but with squigglies and nifty range specifies!!! I like!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rand function to get the random value between the specific ranges. 
Use this code . This following function would return set of element in a array

```
function array_elements( $start = 0 , $end = 100 , $element =5  )

{

$myarray = array () ;

for ( $i = 0 ; $i <  $element;$i++ )

{

   $myarray[$i]= rand ( $start, $end );

}

return $myarray ;

}

print_r ( array_elements() ) ;
```